# SOAP header in PHP

Tags: php, soap

I have a complex SOAP header which fails to pass security on the web service:

Here is the required XML:

```
    <soapenv:Header>
      <sec:Customer>
         <sec:Name>Name</sec:Name>
      </sec:Customer>
      <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <UsernameToken>
            <Username>User</Username>
            <Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password</Password>
         </UsernameToken>
        </Security>
   </soapenv:Header>';
```

And here is the PHP I tried:

```
        $client     = new SoapClient($wsdl,        array( 'trace' => 1,'exceptions' => 1));
        $cust = array('Name' => "Name");
        $token = array('UsernameToken' => array('Username' => "User",'Password' => "Password" ));
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = new SoapHeader($ns1,'Customer',$cust);
        $headers[] = new SoapHeader($ns2,'Security',$token); 
        $client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
```

Comment: I don't see any errors in your code, it matches the WS interface. Can you explain why it isn't working or what error you get?

Comment: The error: xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:ActionNotSupported</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en-GB">The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

Comment: Have you tried dumping your SOAP request to see what is really send by the SoapClient`` to the web service? `var_dump($client->__getLastRequestHeaders());` and `var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());`

Comment: Apparently not working due to absence of WSSecurity headers

Answer (score 0):

WsSecutiry headers are specials and can be tricky to set. They are not declared as the other common Soap Headers.

Your WsSecurity header is pretty basic whereas it can be more complexe when it includes password digest, nonce, and other timestamp information. WsSecurity header can easily be added using the [WsSecurity](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/WsSecurity) project.

You have to be sure of what is sent ([SoapClient::__getLastRequest()](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php)) and you mus tbe sure that it matches what is expected if you don't want an error in return. If you still have an error, you should first contact the web service provider.